# How can we make sure how well the reinforcement learning agent works on a stock dataset?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, testing, algorithmic-trading

I read [a paper](https://github.com/nithinsethu/Deep-Direct-Reinforcement-Learning-for-Financial-Signal-Representation-and-Trading), which is about Deep Reinforcement Learning and it tries to use this method on stock data set. It has been shown that it reaches the maximum return (profit). It has been implemented in Tensorflow.

My question is, how we can make sure that we achieve the maximum value? I mean, is there a parameter or value that can show us how well the RL did its job?